# Parsing XML with createContextualFragment doesn't handle self-closing tags?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I have used DOMParser to successfully parse XML in JavaScript and I was trying to use `document.createRange().createContextualFragment` as the performance seems to be better.

I found that while DOMParser handles self-closing tags fine, when using createContextualFragment they are not handled, causing subsequent elements to be nested underneath them. I created a jsfiddle demonstrating the difference here https://jsfiddle.net/p8mokmsy/.

So my question is, why is createContextualFragment doing this? It seems like the behavior is the same across all browsers so it must be according to the spec?

I'm trying to follow https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#dfn-concept-parse-fragment but it's a bit over my head. Maybe my string is being detected as an HTML document instead of XML?

Comment: Could it be because document.createRange is being called on a html document?  Maybe you could try the xml document equivalent of createRange.

Comment: Indeed, once I figured out how to get a range out of a domdocument, and fixed your xml so it's a valid tag-string (no xml declaration bit) - it works - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pe072Lmd)

Comment: Aha, that does work! I think I read the explanation here before but it didn't quite sink in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment "The HTML fragment parsing algorithm is used if the range belongs to a Document whose HTMLness bit is set". I tweaked your code a little to get an XML doc without using DOMParser since I want to avoid using it https://jsfiddle.net/pe072Lmd/2/.

Comment: Do you know why the xml declaration isn't valid for createContextualFragment but DOMParser doesn't mind parsing it? (Definitely not an XML expert here) Also you can write up your fiddle as an answer so I can accept it.